# Comparing same records different dates for differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have records in a table with different dates(`D_DT`) but same `key`. I have a `REC TYPE` column that has `ACTV` or `DISP`. I am trying to find the records that were `DISP` in one date and were `ACTV` in the previous date. The `D_DT` column is in quarters, so for example '2014-12-31', '2013-09-30', etc. My partner mentioned using End of Month parameter but I am unsure how to implement this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
REC_TYPE       REC_KEY                         d_dt
DISP    CML0010000042001420000000000     2017-12-31 00:00:00.000
ACTV    CML0010000042001420000000000     2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
ACTV    CML0010000042001420000000000     2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
ACTV    CML0010000042001420000000000     2015-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: edited with sample. sorry

Comment: So you'll want to do a self-join to another reference of the same table on `[Table1].[REC_KEY] = [Table2].[REC_KEY] AND [Table1].[d_dt] > [Table2].[d_dt]`.  Then restrict your results with a `WHERE [Table1].[REC_TYPE] = 'DISP' AND [Table2].[REC_TYPE] = 'ACTV'`In order to compare against just the more previous result for each key, instead of using a self-join to an identical table reference, instead join to a filtered instance of the table where you are only pulling the `TOP 1 d_dt FROM [table] WHERE [d_dt] < [Table1].[d_dt] ORDER BY [d_dt]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this will give you the first instance for each key where the REC_TYPE switches to DISP from ACTV.  It doesn't take into account the end of month borders, just the first instance where the change occurs.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    REC_TYPE NVARCHAR(4),
    REC_KEY NVARCHAR(50),
    d_dt DateTime
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2018-02-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2018-01-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2017-06-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000000',CAST('2015-09-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2018-02-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2018-01-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('DISP','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2017-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2017-06-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('ACTV','CML0010000042001420000000001',CAST('2015-09-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

SELECT [T1].[REC_TYPE], [T1].[REC_KEY], MIN([T1].[d_dt]) as [d_dt]
FROM #temp AS [T1]
    LEFT JOIN #temp [T2]
        ON T2.[d_dt] = (SELECT TOP 1 [d_dt]
                        FROM #temp
                        WHERE REC_KEY = T1.REC_KEY
                        AND [REC_TYPE] = 'ACTV'
                        AND [d_dt] < T1.[d_dt]                        
                        ORDER BY [d_dt] ASC) 
WHERE T1.[REC_TYPE] = 'DISP'
GROUP BY [T1].[REC_TYPE], [T1].[REC_KEY]
ORDER BY MIN([T1].[d_dt]) ASC
```

Comment: What do I do if that isn't the only data. I have close to 70k rows. I only showed a few in the example for clarification?

Comment: @DanielBailey This is just some sample data to show you a proof of concept.  You'll need to change the table name to the name of your table.  If you want to generate this report based on your actual table, then skip the table creation block at the top and the `INSERT` statements in the middle.  Just take the last block starting from `SELECT ...` and then replace the `#temp` with the name of your table like `[MyTableName]`

Comment: @DanielBailey Just remember that if a specific key is switched back and forth between ACTV and DISP more than once, only the most recent transition will be displayed for each key.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not 100% sure I'm understanding your expected results, but if I'm understanding correctly, one option is to use `exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where t1.rec_type = 'DISP' and
    exists (
       select 1
       from yourtable t2
       where t1.rec_key = t2.rec_key
          and t2.rec_type = 'ACTV'
          and t2.d_dt < t1.d_dt
    )
```

Comment: Hmm, i tried this but it doesn't seem to be giving me the output that I need. I would like to display the before and after record when it changed, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

use lag

```
declare @t table (REC_TYPE varchar(20), REC_KEY varchar(40), d_dt date);
insert @t values 
('DISP', 'CML0010000042001420000000000', '2017-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
('ACTV', 'CML0010000042001420000000000', '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000'),
('ACTV', 'CML0010000042001420000000000', '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000'),
('ACTV', 'CML0010000042001420000000000', '2015-09-30 00:00:00.000');
select *
from ( select *
            , lag(REC_TYPE) over (order by d_dt) as lastREC_TYPE
          from @t t
     ) tt
where tt.REC_TYPE = 'DISP' and tt.lastREC_TYPE = 'ACTV' 
order by d_dt
```

Comment: What do I do if that isn't the only data. I have close to 70k rows. I only showed a few in the example for clarification?

Comment: @DanielBailey . . . I wouldn't worry about performance.  `lag()` is the best approach.

Comment: @DanielBailey Have you tried this on your close to 70K rows?

Comment: Would I have to manually add in each row like you did above or can I reference a previously created table?

Comment: @DanielBailey You won't have to add your own data, you just need to change the reference to `@t` in the example paparazzo provided.  You need to point it at the table that already exists in your database.  You haven't provided the table name in your question so everyone is using a placeholder name for their examples.  just change the `@t` to your table name and get rid of the code above the `select *` line.